# Easy way of dividing an integer by 3

Tags: vhdl, boolean-logic, circuit

I'm working on a project that is to make a simple music player on an FPGA. It takes a music file of a specified format from the PC and plays it out loud in loops.

We need to implement the standard note lengths, i.e. Quaver for half a beat, Minim for 2 beats, etc. Currently we have a table of the lengths of a beat in numbers of clock cycles at various BPM values. We need to multiply them by these note lengths to yield the correct clock cycles. The only problem is *Tuplet*, which is a third of a full beat.

Without implementing a full-blown divider circuit, are there any maths tricks one can do to divide, approximately, an integer by 3?

Comment: Multiply with the reciprocal. Assuming fixed point, you can try `y=x*21845>>16`. With FPGA you should be able to implement that efficiently. 21485 is a hard-coded value, so you can hard wire it with shifter and adder, instead of using a multiplier.

Comment: You could probably completely avoid divisions if you tabulate all this: create a table containing the numbers of clock cycles per note length and address it with the note length index. Handle the various BPMs either with more table entries or by multiplying the outputs of your table by the correct factor. If you give us the list of BPMs, the clock frequency and the list of note lenghts, somebody will probably give you the optimal solution (or not too far from it) in terms of hardware resources.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dividing by 3 is the same as multiplying by 1/3 (=0.33333). 0.3333 can be expressed as an addition of two or more (depending on the needed accuracy) (left) shifted input values.

```
input*2^-a + input*2^-b + input*2^-c ...
```

Just find suitable values for a, b, c, ...

This works for (almost) all divisions.

Comment: Note that this will always give you an answer which is numerically smaller than the "correct" answer. In the limit, with 2 bits of precision in your constant, you multiply by 0.25, or by 0.3125 if you have 4 bits, and so on. Depending on your application this may or may not be a problem.

Comment: Note also, that it is possible to get the correct result of the `floor(x / 3)` division, if using a slight modification, as described in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a VHDL translation of some code from Hank Warren’s Hacker’s Delight. It divides an unsigned integer by the constant value 3 using only shifts, additions, and multiplications by the constant values 3 and 5 (which can also be reduced to shifts and additions).

```
-- q is quotient, d is dividend
q := (d srl 2) + (d srl 4); -- q = d*0.0101 (approx)
q := q + (q srl 4); -- q = d*0.01010101
q := q + (q srl 8);
q := q + (q srl 16);
r := resize(d - q * 3, 32); -- 0 <= r <= 15.
q := resize(q + (5 * (r + 1) srl 4), 32);
```

Comment: your srl coefficients are wrong - they should be 2, 4, 6, 8, etc (or, in fact, the odd numbers, to save hardware). You also need to shift the dividend left, not right. In any event, this isn't really a good way of looking at the problem.

Comment: The code produces the correct outputs for all integer values between 0 and 1,000,000. I don't particularly love this solution because I find it too mysterious, but I've posted it here as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

If the exact result of integer division by 3 (`x / 3`) is required for an unsigned value of length `LEN`, then truncating integer operations can be used with a little trick.  The constant for `1/3` should be of length `LEN + 1` and 1 should be added.  Truncation can then be used afterwards.  Pseudo code as:

```
C = 2 ** (LEN + 1) / 3 + 1
y = (x * C) / 2 ** (LEN + 1)
```

A Python function that shows and tests the algorithm for all values is:

```
def div_by_3_test(LEN):
    DIVISOR = 3
    C = 2 ** (LEN + 1) // DIVISOR + 1
    for x in range(2 ** LEN):
        if (x * C) // 2 ** (LEN + 1) != x // DIVISOR: exit('Failed')
```

A VHDL module that implements this as:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity div_by_3 is
  generic(
    LEN : natural := 12);
  port(
    x_i   : in  std_logic_vector(LEN - 1 downto 0);
    y_o   : out std_logic_vector(LEN - 1 downto 0));
end entity;

architecture syn of div_by_3 is
  -- Constant to multiply, basically 1/3, but adding 1 to avoid error
  constant C : std_logic_vector(LEN - 1 + 1 downto 0) :=
    std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(2 ** (LEN + 1) / 3 + 1, LEN + 1));
  -- Intermediate, with length as 2 * LEN + 1
  signal t : std_logic_vector(2 * LEN + 1 - 1 downto 0);
begin
  -- Intermediate with full length result
  t <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(C) * unsigned(x_i));
  -- Result after truncation for division by LEN + 1
  y_o <= t(2 * LEN + 1 - 1 downto LEN + 1);
end architecture;
```

The advantage is that a division by 3 of an `LEN` bit number can be made in one cycle using only a single `2 * LEN + 1` bit multiplication.

Registers may be added to allow pipeline for high speed design.

Note that a similar scheme is possible for any divisor, but length of `C` must then be `LEN + ceil(log2(DIVISOR))`, with `C` scaled accordingly.  Please see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2444306/275980 regarding the mathematical foundation.

Comment: looking through [your math link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2444306/is-this-a-known-method-for-positive-integer-floor-division-through-multiplicatio), does $$ \left\lfloor \frac{a}{b} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor\frac{a \cdot \left\lfloor\frac{2 ^ {len(a) + len(b)}}{b} + 1\right\rfloor}{2 ^ {len(a) + len(b)}}\right\rfloor $$ give the correct floor? For the rounded-off value, should `1 << 12 ` be added to the intermediate result `t` before truncating?

Comment: @tim: Pretty sure it does; otherwise, an easy way to prove it wrong, is if you give a numeric example that falsifies the proof :-)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by dieli, multiply by 0.333333.

However, instead of using several negative powers of 2 (i.e. a, b, c,..) just multiply 1/3 by some large power of 2, e.g. 2^24 * (1/3) = 5592405.  After multiplying the clock cycles and 5592405, just divide by 2^24.

B = (clock cycles)*5592405

result = B/2^24

The size of B would depend the maximum size of clock cycles and can be computed by

maximum register size for B = integer of ( (log10((max size of clock cycles)*5592405)/log10(2)) + 0.5)